# No new modifications of files in SD card on PCs?

Tags: android, sd-card, file-transfer

I have an application who works fine; it creates a file on the SD card, but after the creation, I
can only see the file on the Device Manager of the device, but I can see nothing on my PC.

It's possible that I could see this file later, and it's also possible that I can never see it on my PC.

What's happening?

I tried to email the file on the device, but I received a blank email without the file in my mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to arrange for that file to be indexed by the `MediaStore`, such as via `scanFile()` on `MediaScannerConnection`.

Also, you may need to disconnect and reconnect the device from the computer accessing its external storage, as sometimes the directory listing is cached and not refreshed automatically by updating the `MediaStore`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. So I can do nothing in my code to solve this problem ?

Comment: @user2452288: "So I can do nothing in my code to solve this problem ?" -- my first paragraph outlines what you can do in your code to address this problem.